# How to use valgrind for a existing project

Tags: macos, profiling, valgrind

Someone told me that **valgrind** is a great profiling tool for general performance / cache misses.

But how do I use this tool for a large existing c++ project?

I'm working on this project with the **XCode IDE (OS-X)**.
What would be the next step to get **valgrind** working for this XCode project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured out how to use valgrind with xcode:

1) Create new Scheme, no target and enter name (e.g. Valgrind) 
2) Info -> Edit Scheme 
3) Select Executable -> Other -> to the valgrind executable 
(mine e.g: /usr/local/bin/valgrind)
4) Arguments -> add the valgrind arguments (e.g for cache misses 
--tool=cachegrind)
5) Add the programm executable as arguement (e.g. /DerivedData/PerformanceTest/Build/Products/Release/PerformanceTest)

It might be possible that XCode automatically stores the Build folder in
/User/username/Libary/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXX..

But you can change the destination of this folder somewhere

For me this works perfectly!

Comment: /usr/local/bin/valgrind path is not showing up while selecting executable

Comment: @LalithaSyamaleswarich try to open a seperate Finder, and drag the valgrind executable into the selection window, which automatically opens the path to it

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind has a good documentation.
See e.g. http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html
and http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual.html

For profiling, see:
http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html

Comment: already read through the docs. but they show how to start valgrind from the terminal. I'm not sure how this should work with a XCode project.